# PostgreSQL Query?

Tags: postgresql, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

DB

```
| ID| VALUE  |  Parent |    Position    |   lft    |   rgt    |
|---|:------:|:-------:|:--------------:|:--------:|:--------:|
| 1 |   A    |         |                |     1    |    12    |
| 2 |   B    |    1    |        L       |     2    |    9     |
| 3 |   C    |    1    |        R       |     10   |    11    |
| 4 |   D    |    2    |        L       |     3    |    6     |
| 5 |   F    |    2    |        R       |     7    |    8     |
| 6 |   G    |    4    |        L       |     4    |    5     |
```

Get All Nodes directly under current Node in left side

```
SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE ("categories"."position" = 'L') AND ("categories"."lft" >= 1 AND "categories"."lft" < 12) ORDER BY "categories"."lft"
```

output { B,D,G } incoorect!

Question !

how have Nodes directly under current Node in left and right side?

**output-lft** {B,D,F,G}

**output-rgt** {C}

Comment: What is the criteria for right/left?

Comment: B,D,G is correct based on the SQL you posted. What is it that you are trying to do? Please explain what you're after.

Comment: @hd1 position "L" = left "R"=right.

Comment: @JimStewart how have Nodes directly under current Node in left and right side? example [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c04isekortvxk3c/2014-01-28%2007.19.33.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after something analogous to Oracle's CONNECT_BY statement, which is used to connect hierarchical data stored in a flat table.

It just so happens there's a way to do this with Postgres, using a [recursive CTE](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/CTEReadme).

here is the statement I came up with.

```
WITH RECURSIVE sub_categories AS
(
    -- non-recursive term
    SELECT * FROM categories WHERE position IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

  -- recursive term
    SELECT c.*
    FROM
        categories AS c
    JOIN
        sub_categories AS sc
        ON (c.parent = sc.id)
)
SELECT DISTINCT categories.value 
FROM   categories, 
       sub_categories 
WHERE  ( categories.parent = sub_categories.id 
         AND sub_categories.position = 'L' ) 
        OR ( categories.parent = 1 
             AND categories.position = 'L' )
```

here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4a878/21) with a working example.